# Organic Group Permission

Tags: users, organic-groups

I am using drupal 7, how to give permissions for the anonymous user to the view the fields of created from the OG module. The values doesn't show for the anonymous user. In the people permission page, there is no option to view the field name permission. There is only a permissions of creating, editing and deleting the node. Please help me resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used it with anonymous users. Maybe this should help you http://www.modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups

Comment: The given link has a basic use of OG module, They didn't mention how to give the permission for the anonymous user to see the fields. Please suggest me some other ideas.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have "Strict node access permissions" enabled.

On the OG settings page (`/admin/config/group/settings`), make sure `"Strict node access permissions"` is unchecked.

This disables the OG permissions and lets you use the standard Drupal permissions alone.